# Subscribing somebody through YouTube API v3?

Tags: php, youtube-api

There am I again with an other dumb question.

I have seen the docs about it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert , but it is so vague. How do you actually subscribe somebody through the YouTube API v3 with PHP & CURL?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example using the [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/). In the near future it should be added to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php).

```
<?php
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google_Client.php';
require_once 'contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
session_start();

/* You can acquire an OAuth 2 ID/secret pair from the API Access tab on the Google APIs Console
 <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
<https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2>
Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// YouTube object used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check if access token successfully acquired
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // Subscribe to a channel
    // Create a resource id with channel id and kind.
    $resourceId = new Google_ResourceId();
    $resourceId->setChannelId('UCtVd0c0tGXuTSbU5d8cSBUg');
    $resourceId->setKind('youtube#channel');

    // Create a snippet with resource id.
    $subscriptionSnippet = new Google_SubscriptionSnippet();
    $subscriptionSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);

    // Create a subscription request with snippet.
    $subscription = new Google_Subscription();
    $subscription->setSnippet($subscriptionSnippet);

    // Execute the request and return an object containing information about the new subscription
    $subscriptionResponse = $youtube->subscriptions->insert('id,snippet',
        $subscription, array());

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Subscription</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $subscriptionResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $subscriptionResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Returned Subscription</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```